# meaning of ことを言う

Tags: grammar

> もし女神というものが存在するのなら、きっと目の前の相手の**ことを言う**のだろう。

It has been translated as:

> If there are such things as goddesses, the woman in front of me
> certainly qualified.

If I try a litteral transaltion it would be :

> "I am pretty sure that you could say that ..."
> Is this correct ?

Comment: `目の相手` <-- Can you double check you've copied it correctly?

Comment: you are right it is indeed 目の前の相手. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of ～(こと)**を**言う means "to refer to ～", "to signify ～". From 明鏡国語辞典:

> #### 言う
>
> ④ 記号（特に、ことば）がある内容を表す。指す。示す。
> 「この論説は人類が危機に陥っていること**を**━・っている」

So the sentence means "I'm sure it (=女神) refers to the person in front of me". I think the original translation is fine. I don't know the subject of 言う... Practically, the subject is never indicated in a sentence like this.

We also say ～を指して言う, which is stiffer but means the same thing. Examples:

- 祖母とは親の母親のことを言う。
- 英語のitは単数のものを、theyは複数のものを指して言う。