# Meaning of をいいます

Tags: grammar

> 販売会社が商品等を販売する際、その代金を分割による後払いで受け取ることをいいます。

Does いいます mean "is called" or does it mean "is" in the same way that です would?

Comment: Does this help out? [meaning of ことを言う](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82608/meaning-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86)

Comment: A little bit, the structure is a little different in the example provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This いう is "to call (something)". Note that there is no passive voice like "to be called".

The basic verb usage pattern here is `AをBという`, which is "to call A B" or "to refer to A as B". It's a member of [this verb family](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56541/5010). In your sentence, `A` corresponds to "販売会社が商品等を販売する際、その代金を分割による後払いで受け取ること". `B` corresponds to something like 割賦販売, but it's omitted because it can be inferred from the previous context.

So you can parse this sentence like this (it's simplified a bit):

> (会社が商品を販売する際、その代金を分割によって受け取ること)<sup>A</sup>**を**(割賦販売)<sup>B</sup>**と**いいます。
>
> [We/People] refer to (receiving payment in installments when a company sells a product)<sup>A</sup> as (installment sale)<sup>B</sup>.

> (会社が商品を販売する際、その代金を分割によって受け取ること)<sup>A</sup>**を**いいます。
>
> We say it (=割賦販売) referring to receiving payment in installments when a company sells a product.

You can also say this:

> (会社が商品を販売する際、その代金を分割によって受け取ること)<sup>A</sup>**を**(何)<sup>B</sup>**と**いいますか？
>
> How do you call it when a company sells a product and receives its payment in smaller amounts?

Comment: This makes sense, the heading in the original text (https://www.j-credit.or.jp/customer/basis/sales_act.html#trust) is "割賦販売". So the text could be read as:

Installment Sales.
This refers to receiving payment in installments when a company sells a product.

Comment: @mattmir777 Yes, the implied と-argument is the heading in this case.